# Orange Pi Zero 2 Debian Buster 4.9.170 I2C hardware configuration issues

Tags: debian, debian-buster, configuration-managment

I have an Orange Pi Zero 2 and I am running Debian Buster 4.9.170. I am using Buster because of software functions to operate a MiniTiouner 2.0 Digital TV / HamTV Tuner board and LONGMYND Server / Client software.

After I install the OS and try to run the OrangePi-Config, I do not see the HARDWARE selection anywhere that everyone tells me should be there. I am trying to activate the I2C Ports (`0`,`1`) to install a RTC Pi board. If I run an inquiry, I see `I2C3` and `I2C5`, bot no `I2C0` or `I2C1`.

I have tried to include the I2C port callouts in the `orangepiEnv.txt` file. That has not done anything. When I tried to query `I2C0` and `I2C1` it says `File not found` or `Function not found`.

If I could get the HARDWARE select function to come up, I would have half a chance at this.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

I have an Orange Pi Zero 2 and I am running Debian Buster 4.9.170. I am using Buster because of software functions to operate a MiniTiouner 2.0 Digital TV / HamTV Tuner board and LONGMYND Server / Client software.

After I install the OS and try to run the OrnagePi-Config, I do not see the HARDWARE selection anywhere that everyone tells me should be there. I am trying to activate the I2C Ports (0,1) to install a RTC Pi board. If I run an inquiry, I see I2C3 and I2C5, bot no I2C0 or I2C1.

I have tried to include the I2C port callouts in the "orangepiEnv.txt" file. That has not done anything. When I tried to query I2C0 and I2C1 it says "File not found" or "Function not found".

If I could get the HARDWARE select function to come up, I would have half a chance at this.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPFWr.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0WNw.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0sAU.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NppoW.jpg)

I have tried:

1. Re-imaging Debian Buster for Orange Pi Zero 2
2. Altering orangepiEnv.txt
3. Enabling I2C separately
4. Researching the internet.
5. Googling.
6. Inquiring with the seller of the RTC Pi board.

OS Version:
[image: OS Version]

OrangePi-config inital screen:
[image: Initial screen]

OrangePi-config system setting:
[image: System setting]

Debian Buster image file:
[image: Image file]

Comment: Maybe try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may find help in the Users manual, something about installing WiringOP, then i2c will change alot.
Add "overlays=i2c3" to "orangepiEnv.txt".
Make an "i2c-ds1307.dts" file that fit your OS version.
Add i2c-ds1307.dts file to your system.
Look in the Users Manual (Not the Users guide), it is all there

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).